# Python Programming for .json Loggly files

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to search particular strings in long .json loggly file, including its line number and also want to print 5 lines above and below the searched line. Can u guzz plzz help me ?

it is always returning "NOT FOUND".
after this now i am only getting some output with the below shown program.
with open('logg.json', 'r') as f:
    for ln, line in enumerate(f):
        if "error CRASHLOG" in line:
            i = ln-25
            for i in (ln-25,ln+25):
                l = linecache.getline('logg.json', i)
                i+=1
                print(ln,l)
            print(" Next Error")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`file.readlines()` return a list of lines. Lines does contains newline (`\n`).

You need to specify newline to match the line:

```
ln = data.index("error CRASHLOG\n")
```

If you want to find a line that contians a target string, you need to iterate the lines:

```
with open('logg.json', 'r') as f:
    for ln, line in enumerate(f):
        if "error CRASHLOG" in line:
            # You now know the line index (`ln`)
            # Print above/below 5 lines here.
            break
    else:
        print("Not Found")
```

BTW, this kind of work is easily done with `grep(1)`:

```
grep -C 5 'error CRASHLOG' logg.json || echo 'Not Found'
```

**UPDATE**

Following is more complete code:

```
from collections import deque
from itertools import islice, chain
import sys

with open('logg.json', 'r') as f:
    last_lines = deque(maxlen=5) # contains the last (up to) 5 lines.
    for ln, line in enumerate(f):
        if "error CRASHLOG" in line:
            sys.stdout.writelines(chain(last_lines, [line], islice(f, 5)))
        last_lines.append(line)
    else:
        print("Not Found")
```

Comment: thnx @falsetru..actually i am new to programming.

Comment: now i have reached till here, but i m not getting any output.this what i have come up till now import sys
>>> import json
>>> with open('logg.json', 'r') as f:
 lines = f.read()
 for ln, line in enumerate(f):
  if "error CRASHLOG" in line:
   for line in lines[ln-5:ln+5]:
    print(line)
    pass
   print("Next Error - ")
   break
  else:
   print("No Error Found ")

Comment: @user3363920, A file object has a current position at which read, write is done. Once you read or write that position advance. You need to reopen the file or change the position using `seek` method.

Comment: @user3363920, Alternatively, you can keep last 5 lines and use that when match found.

Comment: @user3363920, I udpated the answer to include more complete code. Chec it out.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure it actually returns "Not found", but I put that down to anxiety-induced shoutiness.

`data` is a list. The documentation about the `list` type (http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) states that `list.index(x)` returns "the index in the list of the first item whose value is x. It is an error if there is no such item."

Therefore the only lines that would be reported are those that contain ONLY the string you specify with no other characters. As **falsetru** points out in her/his answer, if there is no other information on the log lines then you must include for comparison the newline that `readlines()` ensures is at the end of every line in the list it returns (even on a Windows system as long as you open the file in text mode, which is the default). Without that there is no chance of a match.

If the lines contain other information then a better test might indeed be to use `x in string` as she/he suggests, but I suspect you might be interested to see how much more processing it takes than a simple equality test. Come to that so would I, but this isn't my problem ...